# thread pool - make a new one per task, detect when a set of tasks is done

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor, resource-cleanup

Running concurrent tasks via ThreadPoolExecutors. Since I have 2-3 sets of tasks to do, for now have a map of **ThreadPoolExecutors** and can send a set of tasks to one of them.

Now want to know when a pool has completed all tasks assigned to it. The way its organized is that I know before hand the list of tasks, so send them to a newly constructed pool, then plan to start pooling/ tracking to know when all are done.

One way would be to have another pool with 1-2 threads, that polls the other pools to know when their queues are empty. If a few scans show them as empty (with a second sleep between polling, assumes they are done).

Another way would be to sub class `ThreadPoolExecutor` , keep a track via the queue and over ridding `afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)` so can know exactly when each task is done, good to show status and know when all are complete if everything moving smoothly.

Is there an implementation of the second some where? Would be good to have an interface that listeners can implement, then add them selves to the sub classed method.

---

Also looking for an implementation :

1. To to ask a pool to shut down within a time out,
2. If after a time out the shut down is not complete then call `shutdownNow()`
3. And if this fails then get the thread factory and stop all threads in its group. (assumes that we set the factory and it uses a group or other way to get a reference to all its threads)

Basically as sure a way as we can, to clean up a pool so that we can have this running in an app container. Some of the tasks call selenium etc so there can be hung threads.

The last ditch would be to restart the container (tomcat/jboss) but want that to be the last ditch.

Question is - know of an open source implementation of this or any code to start off with?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you can use a `ExecutorCompletionService`. It will add all completed tasks into a `Queue` so with a blocking queue you can wait until all tasks arrived at the queue.

Or create a subclass of `FutureTask` and override its `done` method to define the “after execute” action. Then submit instances of this class wrapping your jobs to the executor.

The second question has a straightforward solution. “shut down within a time out, and if after a time out the shut down is not complete then call shutdownNow()”:

```
executor.shutDown();
if(!executor.awaitTermination(timeout, timeUnit))
  executor.shutdownNow();
```

Stopping threads is something you shouldn’t do (`Thread.stop` is deprecated for a good reason). But you may invoke `cancel(true)` on your jobs. That could accelerate the termination if your tasks support interruption.

---

By the way it looks very unnatural to me having multiple `ThreadPoolExecutor`s and playing around with shutting them down instead of simply having one `ThreadPoolExecutor` for all jobs and letting that `ThreadPoolExecutor` manage the live cycle of all threads. That’s what the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is made for.

Comment: thank you Holger. I could keep them in all in one pool, but the advantage of many is that different clients can have a  pool to use, I can set a limit of threads on each, so one client cannot hog too many resources. That was the train of thought. This way can shut down one pool without affecting the others.

Comment: Thread.stop is the last resort -> external APIs like selenium are connected to browsers / external UI and cannot be relied on is what I have seen in the last two months.